# Restrict CreateInstance method to create object twice for a particular at the same time in C#.net windows application

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, windows

I have the following code to create object for Form Type on menu click.

```
 private void CreateForm<T>(string FormName, FormStartPosition FSP, FormWindowState FWS) where T : Form
    {
        try
        {
            var NewInstance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), FormName);
            ((T)NewInstance).StartPosition = FSP;
            ((T)NewInstance).WindowState = FWS;
            ((T)NewInstance).MdiParent = this;
            ((T)NewInstance).Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            MainFunctionality.ErrorRecorder(ex);
        }
    }
```

This is code is in the MdiParent Form and working fine. But what exactly I want is, if again I clicked the same menu, the form should not be created for the second time for a Same Form Type(eg: Item_Master should not created twice at same time and displayed)

How can I achieve this??? Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0):

To achive what you want, There is many ways but one of the simpest is to create an instance Dictionary like that:

```
 private Dictionary<string, Form> InstanceDictionary{get;set;}
 private readonly object obj = new object();
```

and then in your function you test if the window already exist :

```
private void CreateForm<T>(string FormName, FormStartPosition FSP, FormWindowState FWS) where T : Form
{
  lock(obj)
  {
    if(InstanceDictionary.ContainsKey(FormName))
       InstanceDictionary[FormName].Show();
    try
    {
        var NewInstance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), FormName);
        InstanceDictionary.Add(FormName);
        ((T)NewInstance).StartPosition = FSP;
        ((T)NewInstance).WindowState = FWS;
        ((T)NewInstance).MdiParent = this;
        ((T)NewInstance).Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        MainFunctionality.ErrorRecorder(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

and then you have to remove the form from the dictionary when the form is closing.

I hope this help you to start.

Comment: I am just getting an error as "Object instance not set to an instance of an object". in that InstanceDictionary Property...

Comment: You should instanciate it in you constructor or some other apropriate place, you should add this line in your constructor InstanceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Form>()